# Symfony2 how to do hidden file field type?

Tags: forms, symfony, field, hidden

Hi as in the main question?
How can i do a file filed type hidden ?
in builder i can do:

```
$builder->add('file', 'file', array()
```

when i want my form field to by file type or

```
$builder->add('file', 'hidden', array()
```

when i want my form field to be hidden

but how can i bring this to together ? 
so the file is hidden and aslo a field type ?
Is there any way to use two field types in one field ?
Or do anyone have some idea about how can i hide field type in my form ?

Also available answers are how to valid hidden type as the field file type?

```
$builder->add('file', 'hidden', array()
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyDriveBundle\Model\UploadedFile',
        ));
    }
```

will it work like this and accept files only ?
if UploadedFile got:

```
protected $file;
```

Comment: Why do you want do hide the file-field ? Using a `file` field-type the user can upload data to the server ... hiding the field makes no sense at all. Is it possible that you want to remove it from the form entirely instead ?

Comment: i want to hide it couse im using custom js script to allow user upload many files and drag and drop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add extra css to your field with attr :

```
$builder->add('file', 'fie', array('label' => 'My file', 'attr' => array('style' => 'display:none')));
```

or

//CSS File

```
.notvisibleclass{
    display:'none'; }
```

//Form file

```
$builder->add('file', 'fie', array('label' => 'My file', 'attr' => array('class' => 'novisibleclass')));
```